# Issue connecting to Chrome Web Driver with Selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am have been trying to access google chrome through selenium and I am unable to connect to the chrome driver. Initially, I received an error stating my chrome version was not supported but I then downloaded the newest one off of https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads but I still am getting an error.

I have tried multiple methods:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


driver=webdriver.Chrome()
```

Output:

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 117.0.5938.150 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Then i tried this:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

Output:
`ConnectionError: Could not reach host. Are you offline?`

Next:
`driver=webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())`

Output:
`ConnectionError: Could not reach host. Are you offline?`

Finally:
`driver=webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager())`

Output:

```
NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain chromedriver using Selenium Manager; 'ChromeDriverManager' object has no attribute 'capabilities'; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
```

If anyone has any ideas on what might be an issue right now, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello guys so I figured it out and I needed to update selenium, not just my chromedriver. I did so by the following:

```
pip install -U selenium
```

Then I connected using this code:

```
service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

Shoutout to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnY4PZyL9cg

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Python expert but I tried this and it worked:

```
# Configure Chrome options.
opts = Options()

# Configure ChromeDriver service.
service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# Start the Chrome driver with the configured options and service.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=opts)
```

Comment: What library did you download Options() off of?

Comment: from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

Comment: I got this message `ConnectionError: Could not reach host. Are you offline?`. Any ideas why it might be doing this?

Comment: Acordingly to ChatGPT it could be for different reasons:

You're disconnected from the Internet, 

The host is inactive or unavailable, 

The URL is incorrect, 

The Selenium WebDriver server is not running, 

Problem with the proxy or the network. I'm sorry I wish I would be more helpful :(

Comment: I appreciate your support, no need to worry! Thank you

Comment: @JeffGordon I got this message `ConnectionError: Could not reach host. Are you offline?`. By doing some debugging its not the problem with selenium, it is the problem with `webdriver_manager`. to avoid this use webdriver path from `C:/users/<username>/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/win64/<chrome-version>/chromedriver-win32/chromedriver.exe` directly in `Service()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by disabling SSL verification.

```
import os
os.environ['WDM_SSL_VERIFY'] = '0'
chrome_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Reference Link : https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/